# I want to increas my site image

Tags: themes

I upload site image in my theme there is restriction so I want to change the style I inspect element and went to header to know the class name and id so I can modified pair my required but

It was like this

[image]

I couldn't find this class in my style .
class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs rsrc-header text-center col-sm-push-4

I make search the I found it ti bootstrap how can I modify  it 
In which directory is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the image it self, It was so large and in the  bootstrap.css there is restriction for large size image it will not shown in it real size or the allowed size it will be smaller than the allowed size 
I select the allowed size for my logo image  and it fit perfectly 
and the code for css was in A_S\wp-content\themes\xnme\css\bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

In the 'additional CSS' section of your theme customization area, try this CSS

```
.rsrc-header-img {width:500px;}
```

...changing the width value as needed. If your theme doesn't have an 'additional CSS' setting, there are plugins that will add that to your theme's customization page.

Or, you could create a Child Theme, then put the above CSS in the styles.css of that Child Theme. (You don't really want to change `styles.css` in your main theme, as any changes will be overwritten on a theme update.)

If the above CSS doesn't work (because the class name is not working), use your developer tools to highlight the `<img>` element, then look in the CSS inspector to find the sub-class used for that element. (Maybe you need to use the `.rsrc-header-image.div.img` in the CSS.) You can even change the values in the CSS inspector panel of the developer tools to try out different values.